If I'm using compression with ZFS can I somehow request the compressed version of the file without decompressing it first?
Now that Zstd is slowly getting support in the browsers I'm wondering if I could keep my Zstd compression and forwarding the files as is with ZFS.
Currently as far as I know ZFS implicitly decompresses the Zstd compressed files before my web server can handle them and the web server needs to again compress them before sending them to users.
Is there a way to pass these files directly to the web server without the back and forth compression?
I'm most likely going to use nginx or caddy to serve these files but I'm interested if there's a way to access the compressed versions of the files in any software running on linux eg python or nodejs or ruby or php.

Thou can not (lol).

I am not aware of such a mechanism. And it would break the filesystem abstraction concept - userspace shouldn´t have visibility to the filesystem internal representation of data.
I would just explicitly compress the resources and use nginx gzip_static directive to serve the files as is to clients that can take them directly.
However, I don´t know if there is corresponding zstd_static option available.

zstd is not available in the base version of nginx but it can be added through this module: https://github.com/tokers/zstd-nginx-module
